# Combining two variables to form one variable

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a variable $x$ which can be of value $0$ or $1$. Secondly, I have a variable $p$ which can go from $0$ to $1$. Secondly, if $x = 0$, then $p$ is also $0$. I want to make another variable which is the product of these two variables. How can i declare another variable which consists of these two variables. I am using these variables in an optimization problem. Once I would have got the value of the modified variable, I will have to use it to get the value of the other two variables also. I also want to know what would be the constraints of the new variable.

Comment: I feel like there are many ways to do this but how about $p=\frac{2x}{1+x}$

Answer (score 0):

So $x\in\{0, 1\}$ and $p\in[0,1]$, with $x=0\implies p=0$, and you want to know an expression for $Q=x\times p$?

Well, if $x=1$, then $Q=1\times p=p$.

On the other hand, $x=0$, then $Q=0\times p=0$ but $p=0$ as well, so $Q=p$.

Hence, $Q=p$.

As for extracting the values of $x$ and $p$ from $Q$, then getting $p$ is easy (since it's the same as Q). And if $Q\neq 0$, then you can deduce that $x=1$. The only problem is working out the value of $x$ if $Q=0$. It depends on what conditions might make $p=0$ *other* than $x=0$.

Comment: This is actually related to antenna problem. If the antenna is selected, then the power is alloacted so p goes from 0 to 1. What is your opinion if i make p greater than 0 such that p is ]0 1]. it is open from the zero end.

Comment: What would be the value of x in case p is open from end of 0 such that it can not be equal to zero in any case. Will be able to extract the value of x and p in that case

Comment: So if x = 0 then p = 0 still, but if x = 1 then p is selected from a non-zero value? Then sure. Q = x*p still holds by the same reasoning, but now you know that Q = 0 => x = 0 *and* p = 0, and Q != 0 => x = 1 and p = Q.

Comment: However, if you want to know what power *would* have been allocated *if* the antenna had been selected, then Q = p no longer holds, and the only thing you can extract is that Q = 1 => x = 1, p = Q and Q = 0 => x = 0, p is unknown.